# How to distinguish between fingerprint and face id on Android?

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt

I don't see anything related to being able to distinguish between different biometric authentications within the `android.hardware.biometrics` package.

I have found the `FingerprintManagerCompat` that has the `hasEnrolledFingerprints()` methods but I was wondering if it was the way to go as it seems from the documentation that we should rely on the `android.hardware.biometrics` package classes.

Any advice on that? Did I miss something?

Comment: Unfortunately that is currently not supported. I filed [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111315641) about that a little over a year ago, but I haven't really heard anything back from Google.

Comment: I'm stuck with the same issue, Did you find any solution?

Comment: @KZoNE There isn't. You either use deprecated APIs and then you can distinguish. Or you use the new Biometrics API and then you don't know the auth type.

Answer (score 3):

As of now we ideally cannot.
Look into this :
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111315641

Answer (score 0):

`hasEnrolledFingerprints` was depreceated in API 28.

It is now suggested to use [BiometricPrompt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt) and [BiometricManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricManager) instead of `FingerprintManagerCompat`. This class allows for a seamless biometric UI across the device and allows for any kind of Biometric authentication provided by the OEM.

Where you might have called `hasEnrolledFingerprints` in the past to see if the user has fingerprints set up, the BiometricPrompt will throw [an error](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt.html#BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_BIOMETRICS) specific to this.

Comment: Ok, but the error is generic. I need to know whether the user authenticates with fingerprint or face id or else. Because I only want to allow fingerprint and not the rest.

Comment: Also running into this issue. I'd like to direct the user slightly different if they need to use fingerprint vs. faceid.

Answer (score 0):

This is by far, not a future-proof piece of code, but it might just get you out of the problem you're in. This may be what you need.

[How to get list of available biometric sensors in an android device (any tweaks as documentation doesn't state any)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61652057/13664137)

Answer (score -1):

Use Android **Biomatric Api**

use the below method to identify Biomatric available or not

```
public int canAuthenticate () // api introduced android 29
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no specific way to identify FaceID authentication and Fingerprint authentication in API 29 as well.