# Detect separately for availability of fingerprint and face authentication biometrics

Tags: android, face-recognition, android-fingerprint-api, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

My requirement is that if face authentication is available in user's phone, I'll prompt the user for enabling face recognition, and I won't prompt for fingerprint authentication. But if face authentication is not available in user's phone, or if the user denies the option to enable face authentication, I'll prompt the user for enabling fingerprint authentication.

We can detect the availability of biometrics (as a whole) with:

```
val biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(this)
when (biometricManager.canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_STRONG or DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)) {
    BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS ->
        Log.d("MY_APP_TAG", "App can authenticate using biometrics.")
    BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE ->
        Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "No biometric features available on this device.")
    BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE ->
        Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "Biometric features are currently unavailable.")
    BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED -> {
        // Prompts the user to create credentials that your app accepts.
        val enrollIntent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_BIOMETRIC_ENROLL).apply {
            putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_BIOMETRIC_AUTHENTICATORS_ALLOWED,
                BIOMETRIC_STRONG or DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)
        }
        startActivityForResult(enrollIntent, REQUEST_CODE)
    }
}
```

But how do I detect availability of fingerprint and availability of face authentication separately, so that I can display the prompts accordingly?

Comment: AFAIK, what you want is not supported. You might be able to fake it a bit, in that I think face detection is not `BIOMETRIC_STRONG`, while fingerprint authentication is.

Comment: @CommonsWare That would break as soon as the first device with a strong face recognition sensor is released (isn't there already at least one such device; the Pixel 4?).

Comment: @Michael: AFAIK, no face recognition is considered "strong" by Android. However, you are correct that the fake approach that I'm describing is not great and is definitely not future-proof. Personally, I'm waiting for DNA authentication ("Please lick your phone to authenticate").  The overall requirement (do different things based on how the form of biometrics used by the user) does not match Android's approach to security.

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73321606/5790767) is what you're looking for.